# React Native Images FlatList Error "doesn't show the images"

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, flatlist

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slXzQ.jpg)

I relied on this video, here's the github with the video code:

https://github.com/KasperKloster/ComponentsExplained/blob/main/App.js

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qGN3S0wO-OQ

i'm not getting to view the icon images in png and neither in svg, could they help me? I put a bacgroundColor in some random color just to see if the icons are there, and they are, only they are not showing up.. i also couldn't put logout at the bottom of the screen

Settings.js

```
import { SafeAreaView,Text, View, FlatList,
TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, Image} from 'react-native';
import React, {useState} from 'react'
    
 
    
    const Settings = () => {
      const [data, setdata] = useState(DATA);
      const [isRender, setisRender] = useState(false);

         const DATA = [
        {id: 1, text: 'Perfil', image: require('../../assets/images/user.png')},
        {id: 2, text: 'Dark/Light mode', image: require('../../assets/images/light-up.png')},
        {id: 3, text: 'TouchId', image: require('../../assets/images/fingerprint.png')},
        {id: 4, text: 'Logout'},
    ]
    
      const renderItem = ({item}) => {
        return(
        <TouchableOpacity 
        style= {styles.item}
        >
        <View style={ styles.avatarContainer }>
           <Image loadingIndicatorSource={ item.image } style={ styles.avatar } />
        </View>
        <View>
           <Text style={styles.text}>{item.text}</Text>
        </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        )
      }
      
    
      
    
      return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
        data={DATA}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        extraData={isRender}
        />
        
      </SafeAreaView>
      );
    };
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        container: {
        flex: 1,
        marginTop: 20
        //marginHorizontal: 21

        },
        item:{
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        borderBottomColor: '#808080',
        alignItems: 'flex-start',
        flexDirection: 'row',
  
        },
        avatarContainer: {        
            backgroundColor: '#A0D800',
            borderRadius: 100,
            height: 30,
            width: 30,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
                
          },
          
          avatar: {
            height: 50,
            width: 50,
        
          },
        text:{
            marginVertical: 30,
            fontSize: 25,
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            marginLeft: 30,
            marginBottom: 5

        },

        
       
    });
    
    export default Settings;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
change loadingIndicatorSource={ item.image } to source={ item.image }
```